# Rasterio Window on Resampling open

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio, resampling

Rasterio supports processing using window in order to avoid loading the entire image (as can be seen [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html)). It also supports resampling images when using read (as can be seen [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html)). However, I am facing problems when using both approaches together.

My goal is to proccess two images of different spatial (10m and 20m), downsampling 10m to 20m and processing both at 20m using window to avoid load the entire image.

The proccess flux consists in a loop that opens the first image block, downsample the second image (downsample), open the same image block, perform an operation and write the results.

I wrote the following script with small image cases. However I am doing somethink wrong on the resampling/load window for the second image, due to it not present the same shape of the first one. Is it possible to Resample and load a specific block using rasterio considering that the resample block order is important in this case?

```
import numpy
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

resample_factor = 1/2 # Downsample to 1/2 of the resolution

path_to_img_10m = 'path/to/img10m.tif'
# http://brazildatacube.dpi.inpe.br/Repository/Archive/S2_MSI_L2_SR_LASRC/2019-07/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125_sr_band8.tif
path_to_img_20m = 'path/to/img20m.tif'
# http://brazildatacube.dpi.inpe.br/Repository/Archive/S2_MSI_L2_SR_LASRC/2019-07/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125_sr_band8a.tif
path_to_output = 'path/to/out.tif'

# Load 20m profile and block sizes
with rasterio.open(path_to_img_20m) as dataset:
    profile = dataset.profile
    blocks = list(dataset.block_windows())
    height, width = dataset.shape
    result = numpy.full((height, width), dtype=profile['dtype'], fill_value=profile['nodata'])

# Loop on blocks
for _, window in blocks:
    print('window')
    row_offset = window.row_off + window.height
    col_offset = window.col_off + window.width

    # Open image block
    with rasterio.open(path_to_img_20m) as dataset:
         values1 = dataset.read(
            1,
            masked=True,
            window=window
        )
    print(values1)
    print(values1.shape) # (256, 256)

    # Open image block that needs resample
    with rasterio.open(path_to_img_10m) as dataset:
        values2 = dataset.read(
            out_shape=(
                dataset.count,
                int(window.height * resample_factor),
                int(window.width * resample_factor)
            ),
            resampling=Resampling.average,
            masked=True,
            window=window
        )
    print(values2)
    print(values2.shape) # (1, 128, 128)

    # Fictional operation using blocks
    result[window.row_off: row_offset, window.col_off: col_offset] = values1 + values2

# Write result on disc
with rasterio.open(path_to_output, 'w', **profile) as dataset:
    dataset.write_band(1, result)
```

Comment: The resampled/windowed image does not have the same shape of the other image

Comment: You realise the two image urls you have in the comments are both 10m?

Comment: ohh, sorry about that, I was trying to provide some useful examples, but your gdal_translate made the work. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images you linked to are both 10m res, but I resampled one to 20m to demonstrate:

```
gdal_translate -tr 20 20 should_be_20m_but_is_actually_10m.tif 20m.tif
```

You need to resample the window as well:

```
import numpy
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
from rasterio.windows import Window


resample_factor = 1/2 # Downsample to 1/2 of the resolution

path_to_img_10m = '/tmp/10m.tif'
# http://brazildatacube.dpi.inpe.br/Repository/Archive/S2_MSI_L2_SR_LASRC/2019-07/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125_sr_band8.tif
path_to_img_20m = '/tmp/20m.tif'
# http://brazildatacube.dpi.inpe.br/Repository/Archive/S2_MSI_L2_SR_LASRC/2019-07/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125_sr_band8a.tif
path_to_output = '/tmp/out.tif'

# Open the datasets once, not every single loop iteration...
# Load 20m profile and block sizes
with rasterio.open(path_to_img_20m) as dataset20, rasterio.open(path_to_img_10m) as dataset10:  
    profile = dataset20.profile
    blocks = list(dataset20.block_windows())
    height, width = dataset20.shape
    result = numpy.full((height, width), dtype=profile['dtype'], fill_value=profile['nodata'])

    # Loop on blocks
    for _, window in blocks:
        print('window')
        row_offset = window.row_off + window.height
        col_offset = window.col_off + window.width

        # Open image block
        values1 = dataset20.read(
            1,
            masked=True,
            window=window
        )
        print(values1)
        print(values1.shape) # (256, 256)

        # Resample the window
        res_window = Window(window.col_off / resample_factor, window.row_off / resample_factor,
                            window.width / resample_factor, window.height / resample_factor)
        try:
            values2 = dataset10.read(
                out_shape=(
                    dataset10.count,
                    int(window.height),
                    int(window.width)
                ),
                resampling=Resampling.average,
                masked=True,
                window=res_window
            )
        except:
            break
        # print(values2)
        print(values2.shape) # (1, 256, 256)

        # Fictional operation using blocks
        result[window.row_off: row_offset, window.col_off: col_offset] = values1 + values2

# Write result on disc
with rasterio.open(path_to_output, 'w', **profile) as dataset:
    dataset.write_band(1, result)
```

And here's an example that uses windowed writing instead of building up a complete array:

```
import numpy
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
from rasterio.windows import Window


resample_factor = 1/2 # Downsample to 1/2 of the resolution

path_to_img_10m = '/tmp/10m.tif'
# http://brazildatacube.dpi.inpe.br/Repository/Archive/S2_MSI_L2_SR_LASRC/2019-07/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125_sr_band8.tif
path_to_img_20m = '/tmp/20m.tif'
# http://brazildatacube.dpi.inpe.br/Repository/Archive/S2_MSI_L2_SR_LASRC/2019-07/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125/S2B_MSIL1C_20190730T142759_N0208_R053_T20LLN_20190730T161125_sr_band8a.tif
path_to_output = '/tmp/out.tif'

# Open the datasets once, not every single loop iteration...
# Load 20m profile and block sizes
with rasterio.open(path_to_img_20m) as dataset20, rasterio.open(path_to_img_10m) as dataset10:
    profile = dataset20.profile
    blocks = list(dataset20.block_windows())
    height, width = dataset20.shape

    profile.update(count=dataset10.count)
    with rasterio.open(path_to_output, 'w', **profile) as dataset:
        # Loop on blocks
        for _, window in blocks:
            print('window')
            row_offset = window.row_off + window.height
            col_offset = window.col_off + window.width

            # Open image block
            values1 = dataset20.read(
                1,
                masked=True,
                window=window
            )
            print(values1)
            print(values1.shape) # (256, 256)

            # Resample the window
            res_window = Window(window.col_off / resample_factor, window.row_off / resample_factor,
                                window.width / resample_factor, window.height / resample_factor)
            try:
                values2 = dataset10.read(
                    out_shape=(
                        dataset10.count,
                        int(window.height),
                        int(window.width)
                    ),
                    resampling=Resampling.average,
                    masked=True,
                    window=res_window
                )
            except:
                break
            # print(values2)
            print(values2.shape) # (1, 256, 256)

            # Fictional operation using blocks
            result = values1 + values2

            dataset.write(result, window=window)
```